# How to check if a string in a text file is correct

Tags: java, text-files, controls

I have a text file and I need to check if it is correct. The file should be of the type:

```
XYab 
XYab
XYab
```

Where X,Y,a,b can take only a certain range of value. For example b must be a value between 1 and 8. These values are defined by 4 enum (1 enum for X,1 enum for Y, etc..). The only thing that came to my mind is something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME)
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(s.charAt(0)==Enum.example.asChar())
}
```

But of course it checks only the first line of the file. Any advice on how I can check all the file's lines?

Comment: All the lines have only one sequence of XYab? or can be multiple times by line

Comment: One line can have only one sequence of XYab

Comment: you should try regex.

Comment: Can you please make a simple example of regex for my program?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, (modify it according to yours enums)

```
@Test
public void findDates() {
        File file = new File("pathToFile");
        try{
            Assert.assertTrue(validateFile(file));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean validateFile(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        // add yours enumns to one list
        List<Enum> enums = new ArrayList<>();
        enums.add(EnumX);
        enums.add(EnumY);
        enums.add(EnumA);
        enums.add(EnumB);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // process the line.
            if(line.length() > 4){
                return false;
            }
            //for each position check if the value is valid for the enum
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                if(enums.get(i)).valueOf(line.charAt(i)) == null){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about collision but if you have number or string you can use the regexp to do that.

On each Enum you have to do a function regexp like this. You can use an external Helper instead.

```
enum EnumX {
    A,B,C,D, ...;
    ...
    // you enum start to 0
    public static String regexp(){
        return "[0-" + EnumX.values().length +"]"; 
    }
}

// it is working also if you have string in your file
enum EnumY{
    A("toto"),B("titi"),C("tata"),D("loto");

    public static String regexp(){
        StringBuilder regexp = new StringBuilder("[");
        for(EnumY value : EnumY.values()){
                regexp.append(value).append(",");
        }
        regexp.replace(regexp.length()-1, regexp.length(), "]");
        return regexp.toString();
    }
}   

public boolean isCorrect(File file){
        // build the regexp         
        String regexp = EnumX.regexp() + EnumY.regexp() + EnumA.regexp() +EnumB.regexp();

        // read the file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.matches(regexp) == false){
                // this line is not correct
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```